# Azure SQL Database (S0 tier) - How to successfully kill the process

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I am running several DB instances on the dedicated Azure SQL Server. All instances are S0. They all run the same processes yet one of them got into trouble (never happened before). The automated SP which purges old records from tables periodically did not seem to be able to finish. It has been running over 12 hours now (should finish in minutes) and I can't figure out how to stop it (obviously restart is not available).

I tried to KILL the process (the SP in question) but that did not seem to work (see below). Any help appreciated. No need to worry about the data but trying not to go nuclear on this and delete the whole database.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try renaming the database and rename it back or alter the database to different SLO and revert it. The other option is to turn ON / OFF RCSI with rollback immediate

Comment: Seems like a possible solution. I found this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711306/rename-sql-azure-database) on how to rename in Azure. I will try this the next time I need it. Thx!