# How to restore a DB in the past with Azure Portal

Tags: azure

I'm wondering how can I set my current database name `TESTdb` to be restored 3 days in the past. I figured that you can restore the db if it has been retained, but when I do restore a db 3 days in the past, it creates another db with db name + DateTime stamp.

My clients connect to `TESTdb` and the restored one is called `TESTdb_2016-09-27'.

So I require `TESTdb_2016-09-27` to be called `TESTdb` and the old one removed.

May I ask how abouts do I do that?

Is the best way to delete `TESTdb` after the restore then create another database called `TESTdb` off of `TESTdb_2016-09-27`? That method just sounds terrible and tedious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create the new db from backup.
2. Rename/delete the current DB
3. Rename the restored DB to the proper name

Here you can find how to rename the DB: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711306/rename-sql-azure-database)